# Cert-manager: cm-acme-http-solver pod not being recreated when helm delete release then redeploy the release

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

I'm using cert-manager to create ssl certificate in my project. When I first deploy the project through helm. I saw it created a pod named `cm-acme-http-solver` and a path `/.well-known/acme-challenge/xxx` in my ingress. Then I deleted the release `helm delete <release name>` and redeployed `helm install <release name> .`. What I saw is that the `cm-acme-http-solver` was not created, and the path `/.well-known/acme-challenge/xxx` no longer exists. Any idea? How can I create both?

Comment: Does it work in general? Because I checked my cluster and I don't have this `cm-acme-http-solver` pod created, most likely it's created when certificate is being issued. + Which `cert-manager` version is used?

Comment: Check if deleting the certificate object works, see https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/2442#issuecomment-564955495